# How does border with invalid border-color work?

Tags: css, border

I'd like to make the corner of div and img rounded:

```html
<div id="div-with-border-color" style="width: 40px; height: 30px; background-color: blue; border-radius: 4px; border: 4px solid blue;"></div>

<div id="div-without-border-color" style="width: 40px; height: 30px; background-color: green; border-radius: 4px; border: 4px solid rgb();"></div>
```

`rgb()` may be invalid value, but I want to get its result. It seems that the corner-radius effects within the value of `width` property. And the background is clipped. Is there way to achieve this result by alternatives? I tried on Chrome and Safari. `img` elements get same effects by specifying `rgb()`.

Comment: *rgb() may be invalid value* --> it's an invalid value, why not using `transparent` ?

Comment: `border: 0px solid transparent;` worked and brought same result. It's more simple to remove `border` and remain `border-radius` only, I found.